# Secured File download in Groovy

Tags: file, groovy, download

I need to get a file into memory in my app from a secured web location.  I have the URL of the file to capture, but can't seem to get the security issue resolved.  Here's the code from the [Cookbook samples page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Simple+file+download+from+URL):

```
def download(address)
{
    def file = new FileOutputStream(address.tokenize("/")[-1])
    def out = new BufferedOutputStream(file)
    out << new URL(address).openStream()
    out.close()
}
```

and here's my "memory" version of the same function which should return a byte array of the file's contents:

```
def downloadIntoMem(address)
{  // btw, how frickin powerful is Groovy to do this in 3 lines (or less)
        def out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        out << new URL(address).openStream()
        out.toByteArray()
}
```

When I try this against an unsecured URL (pick any image file you can find on the net), it works just fine.  However, if I pick a URL that requires a user/password, no go.

All right, done a bit more work on this.  It seems that the Authenticator method **does** work, but in a round-about way.  The first time I access the URL, I get a 302 response with a location to a login server.  If I access that location with an Authenticator set, then I get another 302 with a Cookie and the location set back to the original URL.  If I then access the original, the download occurs correctly.

So, I have to mimic a browser a bit, but eventually it all works.

Making this a community wiki, so others can add other methods.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If creds on url doesn't work, you can use this. It works for Basic Authentication.

```
new File(localPath).withOutputStream { out ->
    def url = new URL(remoteUrl).openConnection()
    def remoteAuth = "Basic " + "${user}:${passwd}".bytes.encodeBase64()
    url.setRequestProperty("Authorization", remoteAuth);
    out << url.inputStream
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I just came across this today, and it really helped me.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the best answer, as it's not just an easy URL change.  It didn't work for me more for my company's crappy SiteMinder setup than due to the solution being incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the kind of auth for the server, you could put the creds on the url itself:

```
def address = "http://admin:sekr1t@myhost.com"
def url = new URL(address)
assert "admin:sekr1t" == url.userInfo
```

If you're not going through a proxy, you don't want to do the proxy stuff that you're referring to.  It's not applicable.

Comment: Ok, I tried it, no go.  The security isn't that basic I guess.  I think the login server puts information either in a cookie or in the session for the eRoom app I'm accessing.

Comment: Doesn't work because `URL.openConnection()` doesn't do any userInfo parsing.